# Retrieve URL/permalink for a given object's ID obtain via Realtime Updates API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have a Facebook application which is connected to Facebook Realtime Updates API.

So when a post, a comment or an comment's answer is posted in my facebook fan page,
facebook realtime updates API is contacting my application.

I have severals informations according to the new comment for example:

```
Realtime Update Subscriptions received
Facebook RealTime API's JSON = {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"184965658184912","time":1384250390,"changes":[{"field":"feed","value":{"item":"comment","verb":"add","comment_id":"670832519598221_8494151","parent_id":670832519598221,"sender_id":677651107,"created_time":1384250390}}]}]}
```

The issue is that I want to display to my users the object's URL but if the object id a comment or a comment's reply, then the URL will be different.

Do you know how to get via FQL or Graph API the URL/permalink for a givven object ID (feed post, comment or reply)?

Thanks!